# How window.moveto function working on multiple tab open in browser?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have to maximiize my screen for mutiple tabs. `window.moveto` is not working.
I am using this code:

```
if(document.all)
{ 
    top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
}
else if (document.layers||document.getElementById)
{
    if(top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight ||
       top.window.outerWidth  < screen.availWidth)
    {
        top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
        top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
    }
```

Please Help me.
Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

The `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` properties only works in Firefox.

Also, the ability to resize the window using script can be disabled in the browser settings, so you can't rely on it even if the browser is Firefox.

The `resizeTo` method is supported in most browsers, but the ability to disable resizing still applies.

Comment: Hi Guffa, I am usinf IE7 ,My question is that i opened mutiple tabs,that time my window.moveto() function is not working.

Comment: Is that any alternative function for mutiple tabs.

Comment: You can try the `screenLeft/screenTop` or `screenX/screenY` properties, however neither is supported by all browsers.

Comment: hi,,,my problem is that moveTo and resizeTo doesn't support in multiple tabs. Could u suggest me how can i do that,Please tell me for IE only.

Comment: @Pankaj Pareek: As I said, try the `screenLeft/screenTop` or `screenX/screenY` properties instead of the `moveTo` method. For browsers that doesn't support that either, it's simply not possible.